# Export View as PDF from Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, pdf, appkit

[Brad Miller @ Cocoa Dev Central](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000074.php) wrote a tutorial regarding Creating PDFs from Cocoa. I tried to follow the tutorial there, but since its rather old (2003) a lot of code was deprecated. I got it to work after some fiddeling, but when I try to export a PDF, the print-dialog shows, and it does not save the PDF to the file I specified.

```
NSPrintInfo *printInfo;
NSPrintInfo *sharedInfo;
NSPrintOperation *printOp;
NSMutableDictionary *printInfoDict;
NSMutableDictionary *sharedDict;

sharedInfo = [NSPrintInfo sharedPrintInfo];
sharedDict = [sharedInfo dictionary];
printInfoDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary: sharedDict];

[printInfoDict setObject:NSPrintSaveJob
                  forKey:NSPrintJobDisposition];

[printInfoDict setObject:[panel URL] forKey:NSPrintSavePath];

printInfo = [[NSPrintInfo alloc] initWithDictionary:printInfoDict];
[printInfo setHorizontalPagination: NSAutoPagination];
[printInfo setVerticalPagination: NSAutoPagination];
[printInfo setVerticallyCentered:NO];

printOp = [NSPrintOperation printOperationWithView:textView
                                         printInfo:printInfo];

[printOp setShowsProgressPanel:NO];
[printOp runOperation];
```

The complete code for my export PDF implementation is [here](http://pastebin.com/smRA3bQ8). The code above is just regarding the export.

Would be very happy if someone could see the what Im doing wrong here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer to my problem myself here when I read through it again. The problem is with the line containing:

```
[printInfoDict setObject:[panel URL] forKey:NSPrintSavePath];
```

As you can see, the file URL is picked up there, but it should be a path instead of an URL. So I changed it to this:

```
[printInfoDict setObject:[[panel URL] path] forKey:NSPrintSavePath];
```

And wham, it works!

Comment: Just a quick FYI: [`NSPrintSavePath` is deprecated as of 10.6](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPrintInfo_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Print_job_attributes), and replaced with `NSPrintJobSavingURL`, which accepts an instance of `NSURL`, so the original `[panel URL]` would work with that!